# Datagridview Button With SQL

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, server

I Have a DataGridView Calling From SQL Server and displaying in columns & rows the information grabbed. In the last row, I have it as a button with the text (VIEW)..for some reason when I grab the information it only shows VIEW and not load the data from MySQL to the textbox as it should

I've tried numerous things and cannot get it to work with the datagridview button in the column/rows.

```
    private void frmRepoPremier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                string query = "select * from Repos";

                MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                sqlConnection.Close();
                dgvBuildings.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                dgvBuildings.Columns.Add(btn);
                btn.HeaderText = "Photo";
                btn.Text = "View";
                btn.Name = "btn";
                btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;           }

            private void dgvBuildings_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

                if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
//TRYING TO LOAD TO TEXTBOX WHEN ROW IS CLICKED AND SHOW VALUE OF PHOTO COLUMN FROM DATABASE IN SQL

//TRYING HERE! 

 textBox1.Text = dgvBuildings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].ToString();

//TRYING HERE!
               // for (int x = 0; x <= dgvBuildings.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
               // {
               //     textBox1.Text = dgvBuildings.Rows[x].Cells[11].ToString();
               // }

                    //OPEN IMAGE FROM BUTTON
                  //  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
                }
            }
```

When I click on the VIEW button I am going to have it open a browser or PictureBox with a Image (the image link is stored in the sql server) and should be reading it in textbox

Answer (score 1):

I Jason, i think this code help you.

CODE:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string query = "select * from tab_menu";

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=sa;Initial Catalog=EasyAdmin;Data Source=.");
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        sqlConnection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
        btn.HeaderText = "Botoes";
        btn.Text = "Clicar Aqui";
        btn.Name = "btn";            
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

And create the Event (CellClick) in DataGridView

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            //TODO - Button Clicked - Execute Code Here to change the text            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey bud, I have no problem connecting to my server and retrieving the data, It's in my DataGridView (cell[11]) where I have it as a datagridBUTTON and the text set to "VIEW" When clicking on the row, It should display the value from the server (http://www.image.com) in the Textbox1 but it does not it just says "View"

Comment: I dont think im explaining this right.... @Silvio Im going to redo the code so you can see.

Comment: Changed the code...the problem is reading the data from the sql server to insert into textbox1.text

Answer (score 0):

Ok so enable to do this i just hid the column holding the string to the photo, and kept the code to add a button to the rows..so thank you for the help Silvio...appreciate it

```
  private void frmRepoPremier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string query = "select * from Repos";

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                sqlConnection.Close();
                dgvBuildings.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                dgvBuildings.Columns.Add(btn);
                btn.HeaderText = "Photos";
                btn.Text = "View";
                btn.Name = "btn";
                btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
               //HID THIS COLUMN TO REPLACE THE VIEW BUTTON
                this.dgvBuildings.Columns[11].Visible = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex, "Error: Load Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                { connection.Close(); }

            }
        }

        private void dgvBuildings_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        { var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
          if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
          { 
          //OPEN IMAGE FROM BUTTON
          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
          }

        }

        private void dgvBuildings_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvBuildings.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells[12].Value.ToString();

                try
                {
                    if (row.Cells[12].Value != null)

                    { pictureBox1.LoadAsync(row.Cells[12].Value.ToString()); }
                    else
                    { return; }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
```